# Problemas com retorno api em Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou montando o retorno de categorias pai e filha percorrendo um `foreach`, porém  o retorno está chegando no `front-end` como um `object` e não um `array` e o que devo fazer no `Laravel` para o `front-end` conseguir percorrer esse retorno.

> `ERROR Error: "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`

Segue exemplo laravel.

```
public function show($id)
{

        $arCategoria = \App\Favorito::join('categoria', 'categoria.cd_categoria', '=', 'link.cd_categoria')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('categoria.cd_categoria_pai',$id)
        ->where('link.cd_usuario',$this->token['cd_usuario'])
        ->where('link.bo_ativo',true)
            ->get();
        //montando o array para retorno
        return $this->processarCategoria($arCategoria->toArray());
    }
    public function processarCategoria($arCategoria){
        $array = array();
        $cont = 0;
        foreach($arCategoria as $key => $value){
            $array[$value['no_categoria'].'_'.$value['cd_categoria']][] = array(
                'no_link'=>$value['no_link'],
                'cd_link'=>$value['cd_link'],
                'vl_link'=>$value['vl_link'],
                'bo_ativo'=>$value['bo_ativo'],
                'link'=>$value['link']
            );
           $cont++;
        }

        return json_decode(json_encode($array), true);;
}
```

Retorno

```
{
    "Documentações_3": [
        {
            "no_link": "stackoverflow",
            "cd_link": 5,
            "vl_link": null,
            "bo_ativo": 1,
            "link": "https://stackoverflow.com"
        },
        {
            "no_link": "Adventures of Time",
            "cd_link": 9,
            "vl_link": null,
            "bo_ativo": 1,
            "link": "http://adventuresoftime.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "Datas comemorativas_5": [
        {
            "no_link": "Games",
            "cd_link": 10,
            "vl_link": null,
            "bo_ativo": 1,
            "link": "Games.com.br"
        }
    ]
}
```

Front-end

> service.ts

```
getLinksByIdusuario(id:number):Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${API}/favorito/${id}`)
    .pipe(map((data: any) => data ), 
                catchError(error => { return throwError(error)})
          );
  }
```

> component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {


    this.id = params['id'];
    this.homeService.getLinksByIdusuario(this.id)
    .subscribe(
      categorias => {
        this.categorias = categorias
      }
    )
}
```

> component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let categoria of categorias | keyvalue">
        {{categoria.key}} 
        <div *ngFor="let cat of categoria">
            {{cat.no_link}} 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse erro não está dando na seu `Front-End`???

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, isso, fron-end

Comment: O problema não é no PHP amigo é como você trata esses dados no seu `Front` tem como colocar o código do `Front`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic atualizei minha pergunta adicionando o front

Comment: onde está o erro? se sabe a linha onde para

Answer (score 0):

Essa chamada no controlador está um pouco confusa.. e a resposta também. Isso nem é bem um array, mas uma mistura de arrays, com indices com strings com espaços. 
Tive um projecto em que um developer manipulou a API para um resultado semelhante ao seu, e foi um pesadelo fazer o loop do frontend. Não há necessidade desses loops (Com muitos registos só vão atrasar a aplicação).

Vamos manter a operação simples:

Antes da classe do controlador coloque:

```
use Response;
```

Na query, retire os campos que quer no select (Como não sei o que vem de cada tabela, a minha sugestão é apenas sugestiva..)

```
$arCategoria = \App\Favorito::join('categoria', 'categoria.cd_categoria', '=', 'link.cd_categoria')
    ->select('link.no_link','link.cd_link','link.bo_ativo','link.vl_link')
    ->where('categoria.cd_categoria_pai',$id)
    ->where('link.cd_usuario',$this->token['cd_usuario'])
    ->where('link.bo_ativo',true)
        ->get();
```

Não há necessidade nenhuma de manipular o array, pode retornar logo a resposta que vem da BD.

```
return Response::json($arCategoria);
```

O frontend parece Angular. Experimente o seguinte:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.id = params['id'];
    this.homeService.getLinksByIdusuario(this.id)
    .subscribe(
      categorias => {
        const responseData = JSON.parse(categorias._body);
        this.categorias = responseData.data;
      }
    )
}
```

O loop já deverá funcionar sem problemas.

Comment: Ricardo, com isso o loop vai funcionar, mas não virá organizado, deixando o trabalho para o front. Tenho que montar uma lógica de arvore, que está sendo feita no laravel em processarCategoria(). Olha o exemplo com o processarCategoria https://i.imgur.com/KoE9106.png vs o retorno direto do banco. https://i.imgur.com/IEKzSpq.png . Obrigado.

Comment: @Herick percebo, com o Laravel também podes sacar a informação da Base de dados logo organizada, tens é de trabalhar um bocado os modelos do Laravel. No modelo categoria, fazes uma relação com o modelo links, e depois no controlador fazes Links::with('categories')->where('id',$something')->get(). Isto vai te retornar um objecto semelhante ao que pretendes. Dá uma olhadela aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @Herick se me deres o nome dos modelos, eu edito a minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Retorne o dado em json

```
return response->json($data);
```

No seu serviço do angular faça mais o menos assim:

```
public getOne(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this._http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/${id}`).catch((err) => this.catchError(err));
}
```

No seu component capture os dados:

```
this.service.getOne().subscribe(
  (res: any) => {
    this.data = res;
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

No html:

```
*ngFor="let d of data">
```